# Compare column A with column C, Move matching Cell from location to column B on corresponding row

Tags: vba, compare, match, move

```html
Sub Match()
Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer, iRow As Long, iRowL As Long, bln As Boolean, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, j As Long

  If Not IsEmpty(rng1) Then
     For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
     
     For j = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & j)
        
        bln = False
        var = Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 0)
        

        If Not IsError(var) Then
           bln = True
           Exit For
           Exit For
       End If
        Set rng2 = Nothing
    Next j
    Set rng1 = Nothing
Next i
    
For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
     

  If bln = False Then
     Cells(rng1).Font.Bold = False
     Else
     Cells(rng1).Font.Bold = True
  End If
   Next i
   End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

```html
Sub CompareAndHighlight()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, j As Long
    For i = 1 To Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i)
        For j = 1 To Sheets("sheet2").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng2 = Sheets("sheet2").Range("C" & j)
            If StrComp(Trim(rng1.Text), Trim(rng2.Text), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            End If
            Set rng2 = Nothing
        Next j
        Set rng1 = Nothing
    Next i

End Sub
```

I am trying to compare the data column A with the data in column C

However the challenge is , If there is a match I will then need to move the cell from column C to column B on the corresponding row.

Unfortunately I can not post pictures yet, I hope this is clear enough for someone to support me with?

I have improvised to use the "code snippet to display how the data should look assuming they are arranged in Columns A B and C

```html
Before 

A12334  A12352
A12335  A12353
A12336  A12339
A12337  A12340
A12338  A12341
A12339  A12354
A12340  A12355
A12341  A12356
A12342  A22354
A12343  A22356
A12344  A22358
A12345  A22360
A12346  A22362
A12347  A22364
A12348  A22366
A12349  A22368
A12350  A22370
A12351  A22372
A12352  A12357
A12353  A12358
A12354  A12334
A12355  A12335
A12356  A12336
A12357  A12337
A12358  A12338
A12359  A22370
A12360  A22372
A12361  A12361

After:

A12334 A12334 
A12335 A12335 
A12336 A12336 
A12337 A12337 
A12338 A12338 
A12339 A12339 
A12340 A12340 
A12341 A12341 
A12342  A22354
A12343  A22356
A12344  A22358
A12345  A22360
A12346  A22362
A12347  A22364
A12348  A22366
A12349  A22368
A12350  A22370
A12351  A22372
A12352 A12352 
A12353 A12353 
A12354 A12354 
A12355 A12355 
A12356 A12356 
A12357 A12357 
A12358 A12358 
A12359  A22370
A12360  A22372
A12361  A12361
```

Comment: What code have you tried so far?  SO is not a code outsourcing platform.  You need to share what you have tried and where you are stuck. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Hi, I have added a script I did previously to do a much simpler task and used StrComp, however I am not trying to use the MATCH function because I need to know the cell location in order to move it (well that is my take on how to resolve) The second one is my attempt so far, I have changed it quite a bit and currently does absolutely nothing. A point in the right direction would be very welcome! (Apologies for not adding code before I did not expect someone to write the code but to get me on the right track!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to get to your original need: (Not sure what your sheet names are so you might need to edit to reflect correct sheet.)

```
Sub CompareAndMove()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, iL As Long, var As Range, j As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, Chk As Range, LastDest As Long

Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
iL = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 3 To 5
    Set rng2 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, j), ws1.Cells(ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row, j))
    For i = 2 To iL
        Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A" & i)
        Set var = rng2.Find(rng1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not var Is Nothing Then
            rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
            rng1.Copy
            rng1.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial
        End If
    Next i
    ws1.Range("B2:B" & ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    LastDest = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastDest, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    LastDest = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng3 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A" & LastDest)
    For each Chk in rng3
        If Len(Chk.Value) = 0 Then
            Chk.EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
        End If
    Next Chk
    ws1.Range("B:B").Clear
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Original code works fine I made some changes to it to take out the use of the clipboard, I have updated the code in the question. Also reading the code you sent I am not sure it is doing what I want. I will try to explain again, Column A is my "signal list" in there I should have all signals. Columns J are my list of signals which I need to match. In the event that there is an item in column J its a "new signal" that I haven't got in my list in column A and I therefore need to add it to this list. I do not need to delete it from column J I need a copy at the bottom of column A

Answer (score 0):

Sub CompareAndMove()

```
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, iL As Long, var As Variant

iL = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To iL
    Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
    Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C:C")


   var = Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 1)

   If Not IsError(Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 0)) Then
   bln = True

   If bln = True Then

                rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                rng1.Copy
                rng1.Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial


    End If
    Set rng1 = Nothing
    Set rng2 = Nothing
    End If

Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```html
Sub CompareAndMove()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, i As Long, iL As Long, var As Range, j As Long, ws1 As Worksheet, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, lRows As Long, lRows2 As Long, jL

Set ws1 = Sheets("Comparison Sheet")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Comparison Sheet Final")

iL = ws1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
jL = ws1.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For j = 3 To jL
    Set rng2 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, j), ws1.Cells(ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, j).End(xlUp).Row, j))
    For i = 2 To iL
        Set rng1 = ws1.Range("A" & i)
        Set var = rng2.Find(rng1.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not var Is Nothing Then
                    rng1.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                    rng1.Offset(0, 1).Font.Name = "Wingdings"
                    rng1.Offset(0, 1).Value = ChrW(&HFC)
        End If
     
     Next i
    
    ws1.Cells(2, 2) = ws1.Cells(2, j)
    lRows = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng3 = ws1.Range(ws1.Cells(2, 2), ws1.Cells(lRows, 2))
    lRows2 = ws2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lCols = j - 1

    Set rng4 = ws2.Range(ws2.Cells(2, lCols), ws2.Cells(lRows, lCols))
    rng4.Font.Name = "Wingdings"
    rng4.Value = rng3.Value
    rng3.ClearContents
    ws2.Rows(2).Font.Name = "Calibri"
    
Next j

End Sub
```

How it currently looks with your code with slight edits