# Using Match to Color a Cell if Not Found While Moving the Matched Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set up a macro to run a Application.Match to move one cell (Column A) if it matches a cell in Column P to a middle Column H.  It's comparing projects month-to-month so I need to see if any were cancelled or any new projects happened.  But, if it doesn't match to either move it to the bottom of the list or highlight it so I can manually move it.  Very new to Excel VBA so any help is greatly appreciated!

I found most of the code from this forum: [Compare column A with column C, Move matching Cell from location to column B on corresponding row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250374/compare-column-a-with-column-c-move-matching-cell-from-location-to-column-b-on)

So thanks to @Samatar.

```
Sub Sorter()

Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, i As Long, iL As Long, var As Variant

iL = Sheets("Comparison").Range("P" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To iL
     Set rng1 = Sheets("Comparison").Range("P" & i)
     Set rng2 = Sheets("Comparison").Range("A:A")
     Set rng3 = Sheets("Comparison").Range("H:H")

     var = Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 1)

     If Not IsError(Application.Match(rng1.Value, rng2, 0)) Then
          bln = True
          If bln = True Then
                 rng1.Copy
                 rng1.Offset(0, -8).PasteSpecial
                 var2 = Application.Match(rng2.Value2, rng3, 1)
                 If Not IsError(Application.Match(rng2.Value2, rng3, 0)) Then
                    bln = False
                    If bln = False Then
                        rng2.Interior.Color = RBG(255, 255, 0)
                    End If
                 End If

                Set rng1 = Nothing
                Set rng2 = Nothing
                Set rng3 = Nothing
           End If
      End If

 Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with your current code? Please be as specific as possible. Does it error, if so which line, or does it run but not produce desired results etc?

Comment: The issue is that I'm trying to get the projects that don't match the previous months projects (Column P) to highlight them a color (in Column A).  The part that moves the matching project and lines them up in column H works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with a small recreation of your data structure, but you could probably get away with using a single `COUNTIF` instead of multiple `MATCH` functions, since all you're trying to do is see if it exists instead of doing anything with the actual location of the `MATCH`.

```
Sub Sorter()

Dim iL As Long
Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("Comparison")

        iL = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To iL
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("P:P"), .Range("A" & i)) = 0 Then
                .Range("A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1) = .Range("A" & i)
                .Range("A" & .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,0)
            Else
                .Range("H" & i) = .Range("A" & i)
            End If
            .Range("A" & i) = ""
        Next i
        .Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp '<- added these for formatting purposes, they can be deleted if you don't want them
        .Range("H:H").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp '<- added these for formatting purposes, they can be deleted if you don't want them

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Tate!  The issue I'm having is that once I add the code to highlight the cancelled projects it gives me a "Compile error: Sub or Function not defined" on the "RGB(255, 255, 0)".  I've tried changing the code to "Font.Bold" but then get a "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch".

Comment: I do need the code to move any matching projects into Column H so that my calculations for cost, saving, etc will work.  But, I need the non-matching projects to highlight so I can investigate why they were cancelled. I was originally trying to get the non-matching cells to highlight and move to the bottom of Column A but couldn't get code "lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row" to work.

Comment: You need to use `.Interior.Color = RGB(255,255,0)` to change the cell color. I've edited my answer to include that for non-matching projects. The reason you're getting a compile error is because yours says `RBG` not `RGB`

Comment: Thanks Tate! Yep, that'd help if I was coding it in the correct order.  Reason I was using a match function was that I need Column H to line up with Column P not start at H1.  Also, not deleting cells in Column A because I have a vlookup running in Columns I-M to show date, cost, etc. from columns B-F for that project.